# force at least two lines on a page in using lstlisting

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I use the `lstlisting` package a lot in my theses. Unfortunately, it sometimes renders the caption (at bottom of the listing) on the next page or starts the listing at the end of a page, renders *no* line and renders the rest on the next page.

How can I force a listing to have at least two lines on a page?

Examples:
[image: bad wrap]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not totally guaranteed but probably you can use the `needspace` package and then

```
\needspace{3\baselineskip}
\begin{listings}
...
```

The `\needspace` command forces a page break if (it thinks that) there will be less than the specified amount of room left on the page for the following environment. (Stretchable glue, latex float positioning and general TeX weirdness make estimating the amount of space left on the page a bit tricky, but needspace usually does a reasonable job, and the package documentation has more information and variant forms that can do a better job in some circumstances)